# Strings command radix offset not lining up with dd/xxd file offset

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I used this command to generate a strings file:

```
strings -a -t d image.dd
```

This should display the radix offset in decimal before each line. I then grep'd the file for interesting search hits. I then wanted to view the specific offset in hex view for each search hit, which I did by using the dd command (the offset of interest is 32203):

```
dd if=image.dd skip=32203 count=1 | xxd
```

I've tried looking in the immediate context of this offset to no avail - it does not contain the same data. I searched the dd piped to xxd output and found the same data at offset \x7e00 (decimal 32256 - which is the same as the radix offset, just 53 bytes further into the relevant line), however even this doesn't seem to line up right when I go back to view it in dd piped through xxd. Why the disparities? How can I match the strings radix decimal offset to the byte offset within the dd image? Is xxd the culprit?

For those who are wondering why I don't just search the dd output through xxd, the actual reason I need the offset is to pass the allocation block content to another program, this is just a concept that illustrates that the offsets are not lining up.

Comment: Does the `strings` command actually generate a file for you?  I was under the impression that `strings` uses existing files... but maybe it's a *NIX difference?

Comment: @summea yes I do actually pipe the strings output into a file, but the offsets should still be tied to the original dd image file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with the `dd` `skip=` parameter. `skip=32203` blocks (with a default block size of 512) of the file. You can specify `ibs=1` to set the default input block size.

Comment: Note that `count` is in input blocks as well.